# DRF return serialized object in create() method

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm writing a custom create method for my model:

```
class TripReportViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    serializer_class = TripReportSerializer
    pagination_class = TripReportSetPagination
    # To order by favorite count or 'top':
    queryset = TripReport.objects.all().annotate(count=Count('favoriters')).order_by('-count')
    #queryset = TripReport.objects.all().order_by('-pk')
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter, filters.OrderingFilter)
    search_fields = ('=author__username', '=slug', 'countries__name', )
    ordering_fields = ('pk', )

    def create(self, request, **kwargs):
        countries = request.POST['countries'].split(',')
        countries = list(map(int, countries))
        countries = Country.objects.filter(pk__in=countries)

        instance = TripReport.objects.create(
            author=User.objects.get(pk=request.POST['author']),
            title=request.POST['title'],
            content=request.POST['content'],
        )
        instance.countries.set(countries)
        instance.save()
        return HttpResponse(TripReportSerializer(instance))
```

I can't seem to get the right response. I want to return my serialized object, but

```
HttpResponse(instance)
```

and

```
HttpResponse(TripReportSerializer(instance))
```

is giving me the wrong result. TripReportSerializer is the one I'm using for the view.

Comment: You're returning `instance.save()` before returning your `HttpResponse`.

Comment: @AuroraWang oh shoot, that's actually a typo on stackoverflow, I gave that a try to see if it would work. In my actual code i'm changed it back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see two things wrong with the code:

1. To return the serializer data I think you should use `TripReportSerializer(instance).data`
2. Rest Framework Views generally return a `Response` object, which is imported from `rest_framework.response.Response`

Another amendment you should make is to use the views `get_serializer()` method so the serializer will be populated with the context (view, format, and request), which in your case would mean using this code at the end of your create method.

```
serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have to do is, [serialize the newly created **`Trip`** instance](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) and return by using DRF's [**`Response`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/#creating-responses) class

```
from rest_framework.response import Response


class TripReportViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    serializer_class = TripReportSerializer
    pagination_class = TripReportSetPagination
    # To order by favorite count or 'top':
    queryset = TripReport.objects.all().annotate(count=Count('favoriters')).order_by('-count')
    # queryset = TripReport.objects.all().order_by('-pk')
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter, filters.OrderingFilter)
    search_fields = ('=author__username', '=slug', 'countries__name',)
    ordering_fields = ('pk',)

    def create(self, request, **kwargs):
        countries = request.POST['countries'].split(',')
        countries = list(map(int, countries))
        countries = Country.objects.filter(pk__in=countries)

        instance = TripReport.objects.create(
            author=User.objects.get(pk=request.POST['author']),
            title=request.POST['title'],
            content=request.POST['content'],
        )
        instance.countries.set(countries)
        instance.save()
        # changes
        serializer = TripReportSerializer(instance)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```